# about notifyItemInserted in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I find `IllegalArgumentException: Called attach on a child which is not detached` when use this `mFeedAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)` to change data, to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161607/recyclerview-adapter-get-itemview-through-position).

But the solution is to change `notifyItemInserted` to `notifyDataSetChanged`.
I don't want to change the function, because I want to keep the animation. What can i do ?